# Use Path Info in conjunction with RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have a legacy application that I want to wrap in a new symfony project. In order to separate things clearly I decided to move the entire legacy application into a folder `legacy` which lies outside the document root.

Since some of the legacy scripts should still be called directly, I created an Alias and wrote a RewriteRule:

```
Alias /legacy_public "C:\project_root\legacy\public"

RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../legacy/public%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /legacy_public$1 [PT,L]
[...]
```

This works as long as there is no path info involved. For example, calling the URL `www.example.org/showLogo.php` correctly checks if the file exists, rewrites the URL and executes the script.

However, the script expects some path info data in order to work correctly.
When calling `www.example.org/inc/showLogo.php/38` the above RewriteCond does not match, because there is no file named `showLogo.php/38`.

After studying the documentation it is unclear to me how I should change the condition in order discard the path_info-Part before testing `-f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be more restrictive in your `RewriteRule` *pattern* so to create a backreference that excludes the path-info by matching only upto and including the file extension and use the full URL-path (ie. `REQUEST_URI`) in the *substitution* instead.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../legacy/public$1  -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)  /legacy_public%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

The `$1` backreference in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* then only matches upto and including `.php`, discarding the remainder of the URL-path.

Presumably you also have other static resources (JS, CSS and images) you also need to rewrite, so you could include these in the above regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:php|js|css|jpg|png))  /legacy_public%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

OR, use another "catch all" rule, as you did initially (that assumes no path-info).

This does assume you don't have legitimate URLs that contain what "looks like" a file extension mid-URL (unlikely).

Comment: Thank you very much! The backreference-Part was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It would be useful if Apache provided the URL-path, less any path-info, in a handy server variable, however (like you) I've been unable to find one. You can potentially _calculate_ the URL-path (less path-info) in another _condition_, but that would only complicate the above solution and only required if your URLs were more ambiguous (eg. no file extensions).